# BCP in SQL server with pipe delimiter

Tags: sql-server, sybase, bcp, sql-server-bcp

When we bcp in sybase,the following results are produced.

2324336|john|christopher|19900702

but,when we bcp in SQL results are different as below.

```
2324336 |john      |christopher       |19900702
```

Here both the format file is same. how to do it in sql server as same as sybase.

Comment: What does BCP stand for? Maybe you can remove the trailing whitespaces?

Comment: @MatthiasW. `What does BCP stand for?` See [BCP the tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bcp/info).

Comment: might this be because the MS SQL Server table was created with "SET ANSI_PADDING ON"?

Comment: @Matthias BCP(Bulk copy program) is used to download the table data into file.